# Decode streaming audio with gstreamer 1.0 and access the waveform data?

Tags: audio, gstreamer

The actual gst version is 1.8.1.

Currently I have code that receives a gstreamer encoded stream and plays it through my soundcard.  I want to modify it to instead give my application access to the raw un-compressed audio data.  This should result in an array of integer sound samples, and if I were to plot them I would see the audio wave form (e.g. a perfect tone would be a nice sine wave), and if I were to append the most recent array to the last one received by a callback I wouldn't see any discontinuity.

This is the current playback code:
https://github.com/lucasw/audio_common/blob/master/audio_play/src/audio_play.cpp

I think I need to change the alsasink to an appsink, and setting up a callback that will get the latest chunk of audio after it has passed through the decoder.  This is adapted from https://github.com/jojva/gst-plugins-base/blob/master/tests/examples/app/appsink-src.c :

```
_sink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink");
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (_sink), "emit-signals", TRUE,
    "sync", FALSE, NULL);
g_signal_connect (_sink, "new-sample",
    G_CALLBACK (on_new_sample_from_sink), this);
```

And then there is the callback:

```
  static GstFlowReturn
  on_new_sample_from_sink (GstElement * elt, gpointer data)
  {
    RosGstProcess *client = reinterpret_cast<RosGstProcess*>(data);
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *app_buffer, *buffer;
    GstElement *source;

    /* get the sample from appsink */
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);

    /* make a copy */
    app_buffer = gst_buffer_copy (buffer);
    /* we don't need the appsink sample anymore */
    gst_sample_unref (sample);

    /* get source and push new buffer */
    source = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (client->_sink), "app_source");
    return gst_app_src_push_buffer (GST_APP_SRC (source), app_buffer);
  }
```

Can I get at the data in that callback?  What am I supposed to do with the GstFlowReturn?  If that is passing data to another pipeline element I don't want to do that, I'd rather get it there and be done.

https://github.com/lucasw/audio_common/blob/appsink/audio_process/src/audio_process.cpp

Is the gpointer data passed to that callback exactly what I want (cast to a gint16 array?), or otherwise how do I convert and access it?

Answer (score 1):

The GstFlowReturn is merely a return value for the underlying base classes. If you would return an error there the pipeline probably stops because.. well there was a critical error.

The cb_need_data events are triggered by your appsrc element. This can be used as a throttling mechanism if needed. Since you probably use the appsrc in a pure push mode (as soon something arrives at the appsink you push it to the appsrc) you can ignore these. You also explicitly disable these events on the appsrc element. (Or do you still use the one?)

The data format in the buffer depends on the caps that the decoder and appsink agreed on. That is usually the decoder preferred format. You may have some control over this format depending on the decoder or convert it to your preferred format. May be worthwhile to check the format, Float32 is not that uncommon..

I kind of forgot what your actual question was, I'm afraid..

Comment: Thanks!  I am currently manually converting to Float32, but this would be much less brittle if I could have settings to have it done for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret the data out of the modified callback below (there is a script that plots it to the screen), it looks like it is signed 16-bit samples in the uint8 array.

I'm not clear about the proper return value for the callback, there is a cb_need_data callback setup elsewhere in the code that is getting triggered all the time with this code.

```
  static void  // GstFlowReturn
  on_new_sample_from_sink (GstElement * elt, gpointer data)
  {
    RosGstProcess *client = reinterpret_cast<RosGstProcess*>(data);
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstElement *source;

    /* get the sample from appsink */
    sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample (GST_APP_SINK (elt));
    buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer (sample);

    GstMapInfo map;

    if (gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ))
    {
      audio_common_msgs::AudioData msg;
      msg.data.resize(map.size);
      // TODO(lucasw) copy this more efficiently
      for (size_t i = 0; i < map.size; ++i)
      {
        msg.data[i] = map.data[i];
      }
      gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);
      client->_pub.publish(msg);
    }
  }
```

https://github.com/lucasw/audio_common/tree/appsink